# list.remove in python - can't recognize command

Tags: python, list, removeall

I have a python list named "comms_chairs" that is structured like this:

```
[['  Chairwoman Debbie Stabenow ', 'Agriculture:'], ['  Chairman Tim Johnson' ',' 'Banking'], ['  Chairman Jay Rockefeller ', 'Commerce:'], ['  Chairman Jeff Bingaman', 'Energy:']
```

When I input comms_chairs[0], I get (as expected)

```
['  Chairwoman Debbie Stabenow ', 'Agriculture:']
```

However, when I attempt to remove the string " Chairwoman" from the list the following fails:

```
>>> type(comms_chairs[0])
<type 'list'>
>>> comms_chairs[0].remove(' Chairwoman')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#104>", line 1, in <module>
   comms_chairs[0].remove(' Chairwoman')
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Same problem when I don't put the space before `Chairwoman`. What is going on here? It sure looks to me like `Chairwoman` is in `comms_chairs[0]`. My overall goal is to remove all of the `Chairwoman` and 'Chairman' strings but understanding what is going on with the list in general would probably be beneficial. If its not obvious, I am a complete novice with Python.

Comment: you dont have an item with just " Chairwoman" ... you would need `my_list.remove(" Chairwoman Debbie Stabenow")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`' Chairwoman'` is not in `comms_chairs[0]`. It is a substring of `comms_chairs[0][0]`, but it is not an element of `comms_chairs[0]`. The problem you are running into is analogous to what you would encounter if you simply tried `comms_chairs.remove(' Chairwoman')`.

To fix this, either filter out the strings containing `' Chairwoman'` with a list comprehension, creating a new list, or iterate over the strings (in reverse order so removing them doesn't mess with the iteration) and remove each string containing `' Chairwoman'`.

Answer (score 1):

This works on the first one.

```
 b[0][0].replace(' Chairwoman ','')
```

comms_chairs[0] returns a list so you need to index it at well.

Soo.... Strings are also immutable.  Meaning if you want b[0][0] to equal the result you will have to assign it like this:

```
 b[0][0]=b[0][0].replace(' Chairwoman ','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this

```
comms_chairs[0].remove('  Chairwoman Debbie Stabenow ')
```

Also note that you have some spaces at the beginning and the end.